# DRY function in a better way

Tags: ruby-on-rails

could you tell me a way to write this code in a better way ?

## Create an user with data attributes fetched from facebook .

```
  User.create do |user|
    user.email = data['email']
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token
    user.facebook_uid = data['facebook_uid']
    user.first_name = data['first_name']
    user.last_name = data['last_name']
    user.gender = data['gender']
    user.timezone = data['timezone']
    user.birthday = data['birthday']
    user.link = data['link']
    user.locale = data['locale']
    user.picture_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'  + data['facebook_uid'] + '/picture?type=large'
    user.fb_access_token = access_token
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1

```
User.create do |user|
  data.each do |k, v|
    user.send("#{k}=", v) if User.columns_hash.has_key?(k)
  end  
  user.fb_access_token = access_token
  user.password = Devise.friendly_token
  user.picture_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large" % 
                       data['facebook_uid']
end
```

Solution 2

```
hash = {}
data.each do |k, v|
  hash[k]= v if User.columns_hash.has_key?(k)
end  

hash['fb_access_token'] = access_token
hash['password'] = Devise.friendly_token
hash['picture_url'] = "https://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large" % 
                     data['facebook_uid']

User.create(hash)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
hash['picture_url'] = something
User.create(hash)
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord's create method can take a hash of attributes.  Since your hash keys match the accessor methods exactly, you can just pass in User.create(hash) after setting data['picture_url'] the same way you did before.  Tass's answer is essentially correct, but to more precisely match your code:

```
data['picture_url'] = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'  + data['facebook_uid'] + '/picture?type=large'
User.create(data)
```

Comment: What if I don-t have the exact match among key value and attribute?

Comment: Assign the value of the non-exact key to an exact key.